# How to make a tuple-like value in CSS variable

Tags: css, css-variables

I'm studying CSS and I'm trying to use CSS variables.

I wrote this code:

```
:root {
  --font-family: 'Noto Sans';
}

:lang(zh-CN) {
  --font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans SC';
}

:lang(zh-TW) {
  --font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC';
}

:lang(zh-HK) {
  --font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans HK';
}

:lang(hi) {
  --font-family: 'Noto Sans Devanagari', 'Noto Sans';
}

:lang(ar) {
  --font-family: 'Noto Sans Arabic', 'Noto Sans';
}

:lang(ja) {
  --font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans JP';
}

:lang(ko) {
  --font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans KR';
}

body {
  font-family: val(--font-family), 'Noto Sans Symbols', 'Noto Sans Symbols 2', 'Noto Color Emoji', sans-serif;
}
```

but this seems to be wrong because of its syntax. These fonts aren't working on a browser.

Of course I wrote a code of loading Google Fonts in my html file's  tag.

How should I do to repair?

Comment: Use you browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what is happening to the CSS. You should see some warning (e.g. a yellow triangle) next to that font-family setting which would alert you to where the problem is. Trying it with a simple variable, like --font-family: serif would have pinpointed the problem and shown it was not because of the 'tuples'. val would have been the only possibility left.

Comment: OMG. It was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You just made a small mistake. To call variables in CSS, don't use val, use var.

```
:root {
  --font-family: 'Noto Sans';
}
body {
  font-family: var(--font-family), 'Noto Sans Symbols', 'Noto Sans Symbols 2', 'Noto Color Emoji', sans-serif;
}
```